# Installing PostGIS extension with pgAdmin 4 on MacOS Monterey

Tags: postgis, sql, mac, pgadmin-4

I'm currently running into a problem on pgAdmin 4 where I am unable to use the PostGIS extension. I first tried running it this way through PGAdmin 4:

```
DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS postgis CASCADE;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
SELECT postgis_full_version();
```

This gives me this result in messages tab:

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/Library/PostgreSQL/13/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
SQL state: 58P01
```

I looked in my 'library/PostgreSQL/13/share/postgresql/extensions' folder and I don't find postgis.control file. I have also downloaded postgres.app and I would have thought this would solve my problem but it still does not appear there.

What might I be able to do so that the extension appears in the extensions folder?

Comment: What kind of  Postgresql13/Postgis installation do you use? Depending on the way you install Postgis, the location of the libraries can differ. [MacPorts](https://ports.macports.org/port/postgis/) (I prefer this way) resides in `/opt/local` for example. Homebrew  uses `/usr/local` and  [Postgres.app](https://postgresapp.com/) may be too.

Comment: @huckfinn i installed postgresql13 using this https://www.postgresql.org/

Comment: Have you installed postgis?

Comment: I have tried using homebrew, but it doesn't seem to appear. I had also tried using stack overflow, but when I run stack overflow the application just becomes non responsive

Answer (score 0):

I had it easy when I installed postgres using homebrew.

`brew install postgres`

Then also use homebrew to install postgis:
`brew install postgis`

*This is what was missing*

Afterwards, log in to the database with gis requirements:

`psql postgres`

Then from with psql shell

`\c <database_name>`

`CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`
`\q` to exit the shell.

Answer (score 0):

same here ... "Could not open extension control file "/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@15/share/postgresql@15/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory." i had my homebrew/postgresql@15 installed and tested. then did the "brew install postgis" -> which reported to be installed in /opt/homebrew/Cellar (that's ok since /opt/homebrew/opt is sybol-linked to /opt/homebrew/Cellar) and there is no postgis.control-file at that location. but there is a postgis.control file from today at /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/ ... fact is, that i just recently upgraded from 14 to 15 via homebrew upgrades. anyone here who knows how to direct a "brew install postgis" to the location of the newer postgresql@15-version ?

Comment: update ... after uninstalling postgresql@14 and postgresql@15, followed by "brew upgrade" and a "brew install posgresql" ->  PostgreSQL 15.2-3 install worked incl. test. "brew install postgis" responded on screen " ==> Downloading ... postgresql/14/manifests/14.7". that install-process unlinked 15.2_3 and reported "Unlinking /opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@15/15.2_3." and installed postgis 3.3.2_2 into /Cellar including the postgis.control - which consequently ended up at opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/... seems to be a formula-issue. anybody with similar troubles ((on mac M1))?